# Unable to connect with https on EC2 with docker-compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am unable to connect to my site via https though using http its working.
I used docker compose and build it on the ec2 machine. So in simple way i am not uploading any image to ecs/ecr, but pushing code to github and pulling to ec2 instance. Then i run it as i do locally. Every thing work fine except that i am unable to access it via https.
On aws , i have take following steps to configure https

1. Create certificate via AWS certificate manager and verify it via DNS Create load balance
2. Create new SG group having inbound rule for both http and https and source everywhere (0.0.0.0/0)
3. Create a target group with http and connect it to my instance
4. Add https listener and Select certificate from ACM for https listener
5. check target group health and there is no issue
6. Through my domain , ip, DNS name of load balance i can access website but not with https

Now i am not sure, where did i made the mistake, is the issue on docker site or on load balancer site. Though in terminal of EC2, i can see "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" which mean the issue is not with ELB. It is with docker.
This is the docker-compose file i used

```
version: '3'

services:
  django_app: #can be any name, this name should match in default conf
    volumes:
      - static_vol:/app/sub_app/static
      - media_vol:/app/sub_app/media
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_vol:/app/sub_app/static
      - media_vol:/app/sub_app/media
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - django_app

volumes:
  static_vol:
  media_vol:
```

Now I have no clue where the things went wrong. Looking for help

EDIT. Attaching Images
[image]

[image]
[image]

SG for ELB
[image]

EDIT Console after ELB,
I can see ELB connected
[image]

As i am using nginx, may be there is some issue. Here is default.conf file

```
upstream django {
    server django_app:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/sub_app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /app/sub_app/media/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the HTTPS listener on the load balancer to forward to port 80 on the target server. You shouldn't be opening port `443` in the `docker-compose` file, because you don't have an SSL certificate installed in the Nginx container. The SSL certificate you created is served by the load balancer, not Nginx.

Comment: i exposed the port for testing purpose, i tried even without that, but it did not worked. here is the https listener https://imgur.com/a/gf0NfzU can you check please what is wrong in that

Comment: Things look correct in the screenshot. What is the actual error or issue you encounter? You just say you can't access it, but do you get an SSL error? A connection error? Some sort of HTTP 50X error?

Comment: when i try to check website with https, i see this `This site can’t be reached mydomain.com refused to connect.`

Comment: I don't see how that's possible if the domain name is actually pointing to the load balancer's DNS name.

Comment: yes, i can see ELB logs in my console and i can even access the site via ELB DNS, so i dont know where things are wrong

Comment: It sounds like your DNS record is not pointing at the load balancer, it is probably pointing directly at the EC2 instance?

Comment: in rount53, my A record is point to elastic IP and CNAME is pointing to www

Comment: What elastic IP? You didn't mention an elastic IP anywhere in your question. The record should be a Route53 Alias record to the load balancer. It shouldn't be pointing to an IP (unless you are using a network load balancer).

Comment: I deleted my existing A name record which is pointing toward public IPv4 and route to elb via alias and the record look like `dualstack.portfolio-lb-0000000.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.`